# Bugs in Modern Warfare 2 online?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I use to love playing MW1 online due to it's almost flawless presentation and lack of exploits commonly found in other online first-person shooters.
But in MW2, it seems like nothing but glitches and exploits everywhere.  I'm completely checked out playing MW2 online other than private matches. Has Infinity Ward made the initiative to a create a major service patch?  Or have they just given up and moved on with their new game development, Black Ops?

Comment: Should be made cw.  There are too many to count. *tongue in cheek*

Comment: I doubt IW are focusing on Black OPs as its not them making it!

Comment: Did not know that! Who's taken on the role for black ops?

Comment: Treyarch. For the last several games they've been alternating each year.

Comment: The other thing you have to remember is that IW got broken up by serious IP claims, so they don't have much of a team

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was no on-going support for the game tho there were a lot of demands from players around the world to fix certain issues like hacking or exploiting, yet they didn't care.

This was also enhanced by the scandals around IW.

Now they (Activision) are probably focused on more "Map Packs" and BO.

Comment: This pretty much sums up everything, looks like I will stick with MW1 or see how far I get in Nazi Zombies ^_^ lol

Answer (score 1):

In deference to the other posters, I have no idea what the company is working on now. What I can say is that MW2 remains badly broken in numerous respects. There are several uber-builds that need fixing, plenty of glitches, and exploits o' plenty. I tried some online play and found it entertaining to laugh at how bad it was, but that was about it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the other posters are referring to but exploits and unbalanced classes have regularly been patched.  Here are a few examples:

- Models Range
- Models + FMJ Combo
- Infinite Care Package #1
- Infinite Care Package #2
- Infinite Care Package #3
- Sentry Guns Inside of Level Geometry
- Rock Geometry Glitch in New Map Pack (Scheduled for Next Patch)
- Care Package Super-Speed Glitch
- Numerous Modded Lobby Hacks (Don't Leak Over to Public Matches)
- Negative Experience Hack
- "Elevators"
- Some Texture Hacks

And I'm sure there are many more that I can't think of at the moment.  I suggest following [fourzerotwo](http://twitter.com/fourzerotwo) on Twitter.  He tweets about the contents of upcoming patches regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Given that IW has all but left Activision I would assume the game will only receive things like map packs (you know the things that you have to pay for).  BTW, it is Treyarch that is making the next installment of CoD, as they did with World at War and 3.